# How To: Add Style in OSCommerce tep_image function

Tags: oscommerce

Oscommerce function tep_image:

This is the code:

tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . "partners_grey_top2.png", "ksa shopping", "395", "36");

How to add style?

Answer (score 0):

The fifth argument of the tep_image function in a stock version of osCommerce accepts custom parameters.  If you want to add, say, a CSS class like class="product_image", you would alter your function to look like this

```
tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . "partners_grey_top2.png", "ksa shopping", "395", "36", 'class="product_image"');
```